# how to extract zip file through cygwin terminal?

Tags: bash, cygwin

i have unzip v6.00 utility installed with cygwin.

i have zip files in

```
/home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads
```

and my working directory is

```
/home/Zworks/gerbv
```

then when i do

```
unzip /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip
```

i get error

```
unzip:  cannot find or open /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip, /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip.zip or /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip.ZIP.
```

so i wonder how to unzip file cgywin terminal from different location , although if i go to

```
/home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/
```

and do

```
unzip zlib125.zip
```

i can extract the archive i wonder how to extract it from different location

the issue occurred when i run this bash script :

```
https://github.com/sleemanj/gerbv/blob/master/win32/extract_gtk_win32
```

after that i manually tried to unzip files from different location but no success, not sure unzip v6.0 have made any changes or what

Comment: May be try as `unzip $(basename /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip)`

Comment: do you have write permission on the directory where you are trying to unzip?

Comment: ya i did chmod 777 on that directory ,

Comment: @Inian it give error : unzip:  cannot find or open zlib125.zip, zlib125.zip.zip or zlib125.zip.ZIP.

Comment: what it the output of `readlink -ev /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip` and `which unzip`? . Cygwin unzip is capable to understand posix path so something is wrong on your side.

Comment: @matzeri it outputs : /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip

UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Sen

Comment: `which unzip` is a command of two words....

Comment: @matzeri  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/unzip    ,  hmmm looks like its it different location   outside cygwin

Comment: Or you have not Cygwin version of unzip installed or your PATH is not what should be. try `/bin/unzip /home/Zworks/gtk_win32_downloads/zlib125.zip`

Comment: Use `which -a unzip` to show all `unzip`'s in your path, not just the first. Note that `/usr/bin/unzip` and `/bin/unzip` are same file.